# Behavior of file.read() in python2 vs python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have some code that I translated from python 2 to python 3 (there are no visible differences in my example, but it is changed). Basically, my code reads a binary audio file. The sizes of the **same** raw audio file are wildly different after they are read and I have no idea why. The main difference is that one of the programs is run in python 3.8 and the older one is 2.7.

Python 3 code:

```
    def __read_file(self, file):
        try:
            a_dir = os.path.join(TestContext().accuracy_dir,self._accuracy,"Audio") if \
                self._accuracy else TestContext().media_dir
            if "http://" in file:
                f = urllib.request.urlopen(file)
                a_buffer = f.read()
            else:
                if False == os.path.isabs(file):
                    file = os.path.join(a_dir, file)
                with open(file, mode='rb') as f:
                    a_buffer = f.read()

       
        except IOError as e:
            raise IOError('I/O error({0}): {1}'.format(e.errno, e.strerror))

        print("AUDIO BUFFER LENGTH", len(a_buffer))
        return a_buffer
```

Python 3 result:

```
AUDIO BUFFER LENGTH: 3977
```

Python 2 result:

```
AUDIO BUFFER LENGTH: 122400
```

My python 2 code is the exact same except with urllib2 instead of urllib.

Also, the python 2 way is the correct way. My audio file *should* be that big. I'm not sure why it suddenly smaller.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where's the `except` for your `try`?

Comment: sorry, I added it. it was there from the start I must've made a mistake copying and pasting.

Comment: Are you testing with a local or a remote file?

Comment: It is a local file

Comment: What are the values of the arguments with which the function is called? In particular, the values of `self._accuracy` and `file` decide what the data source is. It's likely that they're different in the two environments.

Comment: those arguments are the same for both environments

Comment: [Py2 urllib.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) and [Py3 urllib.request.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) seem to return different things.

""Particularly,
For HTTP and HTTPS URLs, this function returns a http.client.HTTPResponse object slightly modified.""

Perhaps, you can do a `dir(f)` in both py2, and py3 and see if there's a difference in the returned object. That should provide more information